# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] )

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, localhost

---

this is my first time that i ask for help from stack overflow so i don't know how to ask proper questions.
I have created a project with Ruby on Rails and i have installed a theme from this site: https://startbootstrap.com/.
When i run it in localhost i get some error message, example: **ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js")**:

How can i fix this issue, i think its affecting my rendering speed cause the rendering is really slow and some javascript effects are not loading properly from the theme.

This is some of my references in my homepage.html.erb

`<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"</script>`

Comment: How did you install the theme? Did you copy some files? The error suggests that the javascript files which are expected to be in `/vendor` directory are not there, can you find this files in the theme?

Comment: Yes i have copy and paste the css, js, and vendor files into my rails app. The only thing that i have managed to do for the errors and the slow render is a temporarily solution from this site : [link](https://rubyplus.com/articles/4061-How-to-handle-exceptions-in-Rails-5) that helped. For example one issue that i have is, my nav bar when i scroll it doesn't goes white as it should be, that was a feature from the theme.